# Fact of connection to the internet

Tags: internet, fedora

We use Fedora 24 operation system.

We have some computers with confidential information that are prohibited to connect to the internet. But exist some employees that violate this rule. They can connect to the internet from this computers via mobile hotspots or lte modems. I must prove the fact of this violation.And then we will punish these employees by money or dismiss from our company at all. Maybe exist some system tables in Fedora ( as registry in Windows ) that help me to prove the fact of access to the internet ???

Comment: How do you define 'the internet'? If google is reachable? - then ping google and check the status.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes. Google or Facebook are reachable.

Comment: I work in the security department. We have some computers that are prohibited to connect to the internet. But exist some employees that can violate this rule.

Comment: @OlegGopkolov Then you should block such access and not rely upon employees following rules.

Comment: Then you need to inspect the traffic they are sending and decide from there maybe. Or maybe fire wall them off. If your policies aren't working, you need to look at why they aren't.

Comment: If the computers are prohibited to connect to the Internet. Then why do they have internet connection? Why don't you block the IPs on the Firewall?

Comment: @D.A The employees can connect to the internet from the mobile via wifi. We don't have any firewall.

Comment: ... dear lord, please get a firewall.

Comment: Ok, so include any info that is useful. Do you, as a company give Internet access to these computers? Does the employers use their own mobile Hotspot to connect to the wifi? Are they in any case use the company's network to connect to the internet?

Comment: @D.A No. Our company don't give internet access to these computers.

Comment: and they use their own mobile hotspots to connect to the internet?

Comment: @D.A Yes. Mobile hotspots or LTE modems.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** My first answer was made prior to the nature of the question changing significantly, but I feel it still has value so I've left it 'as is'. This answer shows how to 'prove' a machine has connected to the internet.

1. Firstly, write a cronjob that tries to connect to google.com or another site such as microsoft.com -- any reliable site that won't have randomly 'gone down' when you're testing.
2. Add a cronjob to each machine to try and connect to these sites, a simple test is pinging the site, but you could use wget/curl to see if you can actually view the site too.

Example cronjob:

```
#!/bin/bash

NOW=`date +Y-%m-%d %T"`

wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=20 --spider http://google.com
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "Online at $NOW" >> /var/log/online
fi
```

This script presumes that it can write to /var/log/ -- you can write to a different place if you want.

Simply save it as 'online' in your root (or anywhere you like that you have access), make it executable `chmod +x ./online` and then add it to cron to make sure it runs -- you could run it every minute, every 10 minutes, etc.

This [Fedora Crontab Guide](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Administration_Guide_Draft/Cron#User_crontab_Files%20fedora%20crontab%20guide) explains how to setup cron.

Comment: I agree that this is the best way. Based on his latest comment he added that they can connect to the internet to install packages and disconnect. Which this cronjob will capture as well.

Comment: Good job, djsmiley2k. But I don't have access to this computer. I can't create bash script on these computers and add it to the cron. I only can work with info that remains in the system tables or system  cache of OS Fedora.

Comment: To use  `journalctl` is very good advice but I can't see the fact of access to the internet......only fact of the getting  IP address.

Comment: @OlegGopkolov If you don't have the access then you're screwed. I mean you can do stuff like look in peoples /$HOME/.chrome or /$HOME/.mozilla -- if there's cookies/files there from the internet then you know that it must of gone online.

Unless you can set up logging of some form, by adding stuff to the machine, there's no way you can prove something.

Comment: Stick blutack in all the ports of the computer. Remove the wireless network cards.

Or just remove the ability for the users to change networks.

Comment: @OlegGopkolov if you don't have access to these computers then `journalctl` will not work either. `journalctl` can show you though that it requested IP through wlan0. It will not show you if they downloaded packets or accessed the internet.

Comment: @D.A I don't have permanent access to these computers. They aren't my computers. I have access only with inspection.

Comment: @D.A they use raspberry PI with usb LTE modem. Raspberry PI is used as router therefore they can't use wlan and mobile hotspot.

Comment: @D.A The inspection is conducted once a week or suddenly. During this inspection I have access to these computers ( view all system files, read cache and so on )

Comment: @OlegGopkolov so an ideal solution would be to get an alert message every time an ssid appears in the office? Like a WiFi manager that will show you all the WiFi networks active in the office at the moment it happens?

Comment: @OlegGopkolov right now the scenario you want seems impossible. There are too many variables to consider. A more strict policy against mobiles can discourage WiFi hotspots. But you can still get employees bending the rules

Comment: They use wifi rarely. Now they use LTE modem. I need to know some info in the system files. Maybe exist some tracks ???

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1235360/fact-of-connection-to-the-internet/1235389?noredirect=1#comment1808825_1235389 -- Both firefox and chrome will leave tracks as will other browsers.

Comment: @djsmiley2k dnf??? yum??? rpm ???

Comment: Don't know if fedora does it, but in windows you can edit policies to whitelist SSIDs, so the computers can connect to a specific SSID and block all the others.

Comment: @D.A What is the utility that resolve name to the IP in the icmp request ( for example, ping google.com ) ??? Nslookup ??? Host ?? Is exists any log for these utilities ???

Comment: DNS lookup. You could only control this if you blocked all outside access and forced them to use your own DNS. However, if you're able to do this, then you're able to stop them using other access _anyway_.

Comment: @OlegGopkolov I messed around with my Fedora VM. If you want to do this with log files, you can use a combination of logs. `/var/log/dnf.log` will give you timestamps on when the `dnf` package manager was accessed. If you combine it with `journalctl` log files you can see whether connecting to the `wlan0` was to access `dnf` or not. But this is not ideal

Comment: @D.A Is exists any place in the OS where I can find such information: 28 Jul 2017 16:00:00 name = facebook.com ip = 31.13.71.36 DNSRESOLVE status = SUCCESS

Comment: @OlegGopkolov do `less /var/log/dnf.log` on one terminal to see access to `dnf` and  `journalctl -u NetworkManager.service` on another terminal to see access to a wifi network . Compare timestamps and see if they are the same. `dnf.log` will show you which packets were installed, removed, upgraded and when

Comment: @OlegGopkolov you will not accomplish this with the ease you want, unless you can either lock down access, or give yourself access that is higher than the user has. You need to either stop them connecting to other access (by removing their rights) or add the scripts I gave you, to monitor what they are doing.

Comment: @djsmiley2k How can I lock down access to the LTE network ??? I don't have any access to the LTE base station.

Comment: @djsmiley2k I can only inspect system files of OS Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you want to define the 'internet' and being able to send data to/from it.

A simple test is to see if you can ping google.com, if this works, surely you're connected?

Well it's not that simple, maybe http is blocked, maybe https is blocked... or maybe icmp is blocked so the ping fails but web pages load?

A better idea is to think about 'why' you care if the system is connected -- if you're trying to send data somewhere, attempt to do so and deal with not being able to, rather than trying to check for the right conditions without attempting it.

This is a common [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/168762), and so it's very difficult to give you better advice than this.

Comment: I work in the security department. We have some computers that are prohibited to connect to the internet. But exist some employees that can violate this rule. My task is prove that this computer was connected to the internet.

Comment: That's not what he asks. He wants to find a way to check whether a computer has connected to the internet or not. Not if it has internet connection.

Comment: @D.A he's just commented on the original question, it seems he DOES want to know if it's got an internet connection after all.

Comment: Well not really. I don't think that it is phrased in the best way. To my understanding the computers have internet connection, and he wants to know if the employee used the Internet.

Comment: @D.A I think it may be a language issue. The OP has said "We have some computers that are prohibited to connect to the internet. But exist some employees that can violate this rule"

Comment: When I come with examination to the room with employees ( that are prohibited to connect to the internet )  100 % this computers are out of the internet but i must to prove the fact that was (in the past) connected to the internet

Comment: Maybe exist some system table in which remain some stamps of the internet connection or maybe remain any cache.

Comment: @DavidPostill lots of info is missing as you see. Employees use hotspot to connect the internet. And he wants to prove that the computer had Internet access. Last Comment "No. Our company don't give internet access to these computers"

Comment: @D.A Maybe exist some system tables in which remain some stamps of the internet connection or maybe remain any cache

Comment: @OlegGopkolov we will figure this out once we get all the info correct

Comment: @D.A We have some computers with confidential information that are prohibited to connect to the internet. But exist some employees that violate this rule. They can connect to the internet from this computers via mobile hotspots or lte modems. I must prove the fact of this violation.And then we will punish these employees by money or dismiss from your company at all. Maybe exist some system tables in Fedora ( as registry in Windows ) that help me to prove the fact of access to the internet ???

Comment: @OlegGopkolov you could try https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_channel_monitor.html it lists all the people on an access point of your choice, and can even play noises when people connect.

Comment: @иσαнcяişтiпσ this tool is for windows. We are talking about linux

Comment: Write a cronjob to ping google.com every 30 seconds. Have it log to a file when it succeeds.

Comment: @D.A why can't you just use wine?

Comment: why has no one mentioned outright removing NetworkManager-wwan (for broadband connections) and make it a protected package outside of the permissions of the $user(s) to re-add? same with NetworkManager-wifi OR scape /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ for any ifcfg-* that are not authorized?